# finding out length in dimensional weight?

Tags: volume

I have this formula:

```
l*w*h (Length*width*height) = dimensional weight
```

if I have only width and height can I figure out length and find out weight?
I am using getting my data from the Kinect to plug into the formula but it does not do length as far as I know.

Comment: Note:If I do not have enough data to figure out weight then please suggest a different formula that uses width, height, and any other variables you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You have one equation in two unknowns, so will not be able to find a solution without another piece of data.

Comment: If you have a formula I can use to guess the weight within a 5-6% error rate I will accept that as an answer if you think their is not enough data to answer the above question directly. Must use height and width though but other variables you add to solve the problem are fine.

Comment: Do you have a photo or something of the package to guess the length?  That is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

(Length*width*height)=volume

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_weight

Dimensional weight is a calculation of a theoretical weight of a package. This theoretical weight is the weight of the package at a minimum density chosen by the freight carrier. If the package is below this minimum density, then the actual weight is irrelevant as the freight carrier will charge for the volume of the package as if it were of the chosen density (what the package would weigh at the minimum density).